# Inserting image by Ooxml not working in Word Online

Tags: office-js

I am trying to insert an image in a contentcontrol by Ooxml because I want different textwrapping than inline. This works fine in Word Desktop, but fails in Word Online. First time it seems to insert the picture but a second time it throws a "Not Allowed" error. Document needs to be refreshed afterwards.

This is the script lab code to reproduce:

```
$("#run").click(() => tryCatch(run));
$("#ooxml").click(() => tryCatch(getooxml));

let ooxml = '<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?><?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?><pkg:package xmlns:pkg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/xmlPackage"><pkg:part pkg:name="/_rels/.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="512"><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId1" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/officeDocument" Target="word/document.xml"/></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/_rels/document.xml.rels" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml" pkg:padding="256"><pkg:xmlData><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"><Relationship Id="rId4" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/image" Target="media/image1.png"/></Relationships></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/document.xml" pkg:contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document.main+xml"><pkg:xmlData><w:document xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape"><w:body><w:drawing><wp:anchor distT="0" distB="0" distL="0" distR="0" simplePos="0" relativeHeight="251658240" behindDoc="0" locked="1" layoutInCell="1" allowOverlap="1"><wp:simplePos x="0" y="0" /><wp:positionH relativeFrom="character"><wp:align>left</wp:align></wp:positionH><wp:positionV relativeFrom="line"><wp:align>top</wp:align></wp:positionV><wp:extent cx="2628900" cy="1743075"/><wp:wrapSquare wrapText="bothSides"/><!--<wp:wrapNone/>--><wp:effectExtent l="0" t="0" r="0" b="0"/><wp:docPr id="3" name="Picture 3" descr="" /><wp:cNvGraphicFramePr><a:graphicFrameLocks noChangeAspect="1" noResize="0" xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"/></wp:cNvGraphicFramePr><a:graphic xmlns:a="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/main"><a:graphicData uri="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"><pic:pic xmlns:pic="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/picture"><pic:nvPicPr><pic:cNvPr id="2" name="Image.png"/><pic:cNvPicPr/></pic:nvPicPr><pic:blipFill><a:blip r:embed="rId4"></a:blip><a:stretch><a:fillRect/></a:stretch></pic:blipFill><pic:spPr><a:xfrm><a:off x="0" y="0"/><a:ext cx="2628900" cy="1743075"/></a:xfrm><a:prstGeom prst="rect"><a:avLst/></a:prstGeom></pic:spPr></pic:pic></a:graphicData></a:graphic></wp:anchor></w:drawing></w:body></w:document></pkg:xmlData></pkg:part><pkg:part pkg:name="/word/media/image1.png" pkg:contentType="image/png" pkg:compression="store"><pkg:binaryData>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</pkg:binaryData></pkg:part></pkg:package>';

async function run() {
  await Word.run(async (context) => {
    let controls = context.document.contentControls;
    controls.load("items");
    await context.sync();
    controls.items[0].insertOoxml(ooxml, "Replace");

    await context.sync();
  });
}

async function getooxml() {
  await Word.run(async (context) => {
    let controls = context.document.contentControls;
    controls.load("items, ooxml");
    await context.sync();
    let controlOoxml = controls.items[0].getOoxml();
    await context.sync();
    console.log(controlOoxml);

  });
}

/** Default helper for invoking an action and handling errors. */
async function tryCatch(callback) {
  try {
    await callback();
  } catch (error) {
    // Note: In a production add-in, you'd want to notify the user through your add-in's UI.
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```